# Download an instagram image in android

Tags: android, android-studio, instagram, downloadfileasync

I want do download an image of intagram by know the url of that, like: `https://www.instagram.com/p/BAKQchetc` but when I use tihs URL it gives me to the instagram page, and I want to see only the image, what can I do?

(I'm using [FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) to download images)

Comment: you need to use the instagram api. Here is the doc page https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: yes but i'm reading and idk how to make it.... T.T

Answer (score 2):

Append /media/?size=l to https://www.instagram.com/p/BAKQchetc and you will receive image data only.

Comment: The URL was broken

Answer (score 1):

step 1 : copy URL, it must look like this : https://www.instagram.com/p/CRIpFwTLJvW/?utm_medium=copy_link

step 2 : now remove "utm_medium=copy_link" part from URL and replace with "__a=1"

step 3 : Run this URL in postman and you will get the response

step 4 : Search og:image in response you will find <meta content simply copy that link and paste in any browser and you will find photo or video (For Html)

Note: you can use JSON formatter to formate Jason response and easily find display url in json fromate